# Find the smallest real number $a\gt 0$ for which the equation $a^x=x$ has no real solutions

Tags: calculus

As the title says,

> We seek the smallest real number $a\gt 0$ for which the equation $a^x=x$ has no real solutions.

This is inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985849/how-to-prove-that-ex-x-has-no-real-solution) question.

I must admit that I did not have much luck with this..Any suggestions?

Comment: Is $a$ allowed to be negative?  For a given $a$, does the graph of $f(x) = a^{x}$ intersect the graph of $g(x) = x$?

Comment: $a\gt 0$ I will edit. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: You shouldn't accept a wrong answer. Numerically, $a\le 1.4446678610\cdots$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust You are-obviously-right. Some time has passed since I asked this, I believe I did not review the "accepted" answer properly. Also, thank you for the answer and the graph you provided.

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution, which I can't guarantee is correct or as rigorous as one would like.

First note that for $a \le 1$ it is trivial to see that real solutions exist, so we can focus on the $a > 1$ case.

The idea then is to determine when the curves $a^x$ and $x$ intersects, which is exactly when the equation has solutions. So first reformulate it as a function and calculate it's derivatives:

$$
f(x) = a^x - x \\
f'(x) = ln(a)a^x - 1\\
f''(x) = ln(a)^2a^x
$$

Then use the derivatives to calculate $x_{min}$ for $f$, which is just number crunching and you get:
$$
-\frac{\ln(\ln a)}{\ln a}
$$
Then insert it into $f$ to get its $y_{min}$:
$$
\frac{1 + \ln(\ln a)}{\ln a}
$$
So if $y_{min} > 0$ the curves *does not* interest and no real solutions exist.

$$
\frac{1 + \ln(\ln a)}{\ln a} = 0 \\
\iff \ln(\ln a) = -1
\iff a = e^\frac{1}{e}
$$

In other words, solutions exist iff $0 < a \leq e^\frac{1}{e}$.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, $x\ge0$. From the equation, we draw

$$a=\sqrt[x]x.$$

This function has a single maximum at $x=e$, so that

$$a\le \sqrt[e]e.$$

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, this solution is not quite accurate. See [Björn Lindqvist's solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2174154/167197).

---

---

Let $f(x) = a^x$. The idea is that we need to find the value of $x$ such that $f'(x) = 1$ and this point $x$ equals $a^x.$ The derivative is $f'(x) = \ln(a)a^x$. Setting this equal to one and solving for $x$ we see that

$$
x = -\ln(\ln(a))\;.
$$

So our point is $(-\ln(\ln(a)),a^{-\ln(\ln(a))})$, and we need to lie on the line $y=x$, so we need the solution to the equation

$$
-\ln(\ln(a))\;\;=\;\;a^{-\ln(\ln(a))}\;.
$$

I'm not sure if there is a way to solve for $a$ explicitly, but [putting this into WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-ln(ln(x))+%3D+x%5E(-ln(ln(x)))) we get the approximation $a \approx 1.27627610348955$. WolframAlpha, OEIS, and a brief Google search indicate that this isn't some known (or popular) constant.

Comment: Thank you for this! I was actually hoping that this was indeed a "known" constant of some worth. If there is a way to solve explicitly, it would be nice to have more info on it. Thanks again..

Comment: But if $a$ is 1, $1^x = x$ has the solution 1. Doesn't that contradict your answer?

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist I don't think so. That constant in my answer is the smallest real number $a$ such that $a^x=x$ has *no* real solutions. For any value of $a$ less than that constant, it's fine for that equation to have solutions.

Comment: You are right. But now I think there are some a's that are larger than what you have calculated that have real solutions. E.g $1.4^x = x$ is solvable. I think $a$ should be $e^{1/e}$.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist yeah, just looking at the graphs of the curve $e^{x/e}$ and $x$ you are definitely correct. I'll try to figure out exactly what's wrong with my approach and calculation later, but until then you should type up what you've got as an answer.